# Navbar overlapping on certain computers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, compatibility

This is my first question, and I was somewhat hesitant to ask because the code in question works fine on my computer, it is only when demoed in an office environment (they use Internet Explorer 11, although everything works fine using IE11 from my home computer) that it runs into issues. I've extensively researched compatibility mode, etc. but on their computers the Navbar always overlaps the content. I am using Bootstrap and very minimal CSS. The html table is repeated a lot just to test the scrolling function (fixed navbar). If anyone has any insight to offer, or can spot anything in my code that could be causing this, I would appreciate it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 
    <title>Order</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>

        body {
            padding-top: 125px;
        }

        #header {
            height: 105px;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- Static header with order information -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row" id="header">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <strong>Order#: </strong>%orderNumber
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <strong>Order Date: </strong>%orderDate
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <strong>Customer #: </strong>%customerNumber
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <strong>CustomerName: </strong>%customerName
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <strong>Changed By: </strong>%changedBy
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Adaptive Table -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <table class="col-sm-12 table-striped table-condensed">         
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item #</th>
                        <th>Old Qty</th>
                        <th>New Qty</th>
                        <th>Stock</th>
                        <th>Cust Ord</th>
                        <th>Vend Ord</th>
                        <th>Min</th>
                        <th>Max</th>
                        <th>Usage</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>            
                <tbody>                 
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-title="Item #">%itemNum</td>
                        <td data-title="Old Qty">%old</td>
                        <td data-title="New Qty">%new</td>
                        <td data-title="Stock">%stock</td>
                        <td data-title="Cust Ord">%custOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Vend Ord">%vendOrd</td>
                        <td data-title="Min">%min</td>
                        <td data-title="Max">%max</td>
                        <td data-title="Usage">%use</td>
                    </tr>      
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to pinpoint what the exact problem could be without seeing how the navbar is actually breaking in IE11. There's most likely a problem because your navbar's position is fixed and IE is not dealing with it as expected.

Here's a couple things I would try doing that might help isolate the source of the problem:

1. Try removing `height:105px` on `#header`. It's possible your header content might be overflowing the navbar.
2. Try replacing padding on your body class with padding or margin on the div that contains your table instead.